# Почему стили и изображения не подключаются из папки public?

Tags: php, laravel, http

Храню изображения и стили в паке `resources` которые потом с помощью mix'а записываю в папку `public`. И они корректно работают на главной странице. Но когда я перехожу на страницу с новостями типа `127.0.0.1:8000/news/...` стили и изображения пытаются подключатся не из папки `public` а из `public/news/...`. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: так может указывать стоит путь от корня, а не просто `src="img.jpg"`?

Comment: @teran Я пытался указывать путь от корня, типа `src="public/img/img.jpg`, но это не решает проблему. Он все так же пытается искать папку news и путь получается вот такой `src="news/public/img/img.jpg`

Comment: конечно не решает, потому что `public` не надо писать. корень  в вашем случае начинается с `/`, т.е. `src="/img/img.jpg"`

Comment: @teran Попробовал убрать `public`, но все равно та же ошибка. Те же стили пытаются найти по адресу `http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/css/all.css`

Comment: и стили у вас при этом написаны как `<link href="/css/all.css" ...` а не `href="css/all.css"` ?

Comment: В Laravel есть хелпер для blade шаблонов называемый [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-asset)

Comment: @teran Черт, добавив `/` перед `css/all.css` все заработало... Я час ломал голову, а ошибка оказалась в черточке... Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

В Laravel существует хелпер asset(), который создает полный путь, чтобы исключить проблемы с загрузкой JS, CSS, изображений.

Пример:

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/script.js') }}"></script>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-asset